# Rendering a fullscreen quad using WebGL

Tags: webgl, framebuffer

I have a framebuffer to which I rendered my scene and now I want to render this to a "fullscreen" quad. How can I set my camera and what should I put in my vertex shader in order to render the framebuffer's texture to the whole screen.

I've tried creating a fullscreen quad like this

```
var gl = this.gl;
var quad_vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var quad_vertex_buffer_data = new Float32Array([ 
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0,  1.0, 0.0]);
gl.bufferData(quad_vertex_buffer, quad_vertex_buffer_data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
//gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0, 6);
```

but it still renders everything black. Any ideeas or examples/tutorials I can follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really not a big deal, once you get how to use Vertex Buffers and shaders. Then you can easily write an utility function to do it. Here is one I normally use, if you are looking for a reference:

```
drawFullScreenQuad : function(shaderProgram) {

    if (!shaderProgram)
    {
        utils.warning("Missing the shader program!");
        return;
    }

    // Only created once
    if (this.screenQuadVBO == null)
    {
        var verts = [
            // First triangle:
             1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,
            // Second triangle:
            -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0
        ];
        this.screenQuadVBO = this.gl.createBuffer();
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.screenQuadVBO);
        this.gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), this.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    // Bind:
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.screenQuadVBO);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexAttributes.vertexPositionNDC);
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexAttributes.vertexPositionNDC, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Draw 6 vertexes => 2 triangles:
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // Cleanup:
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
},
```

Then you can go fancy like I did and compute the texture coordinates on-the-fly in the vertex shader:

**Vertex Shader:**

```
precision lowp float;

// xy = vertex position in normalized device coordinates ([-1,+1] range).
attribute vec2 vertexPositionNDC;

varying vec2 vTexCoords;

const vec2 scale = vec2(0.5, 0.5);

void main()
{
    vTexCoords  = vertexPositionNDC * scale + scale; // scale vertex attribute to [0,1] range
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPositionNDC, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D colorMap;
varying vec2 vTexCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorMap, vTexCoords);
}
```

The important point to note are the vertexes in Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC), so you just pass the vertexes in the [-1,1] range and forward them directly to `gl_Position` without the need to multiply by a projection matrix.

Comment: I'm getting a `Error: program.vertexAttributes is undefined` on `this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexAttributes.vertexPositionNDC);`  what did i forget?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, `shaderProgram` is a user defined type, not a WebGL builtin, so you need to define your own. That code snipped is not complete, it is just for demonstration.

Comment: a, tnx. I'm just started to checkout the webgl. i did some dx11, but it's still a change..

Comment: FYI: NDC is after the perspective divide (see GL spec). Did you mean clip space coordinates?

Comment: @gman, yes you are correct. I always used to get the terminology wrong. That is indeed clip space, not ndc.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need a camera to render a fullscreen quad? Rendering a fullscreen quad is pretty much the simplest thing you can do in WebGL. Given the buffer you already setup just use a shader like this

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 v_position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = v_position;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1); // green
}
```

You should get a green screen.

There's a few bugs in the code though. You need to bind the buffer *before* you try up put data in it. You need to reference the buffer through the bind point, not the buffer object.

old (incorrect)

```
gl.bufferData(quad_vertex_buffer, quad_vertex_buffer_data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer);
```

new (correct)

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer_data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Example:

```js
const vs = `
    attribute vec4 v_position;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = v_position;
    }     
`;

const fs = `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
       gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1); // green
    }
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var shader_program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(shader_program);
var vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shader_program, "v_position");
var quad_vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var quad_vertex_buffer_data = new Float32Array([ 
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0,  1.0, 0.0]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer_data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute)
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Another example with a simple pattern to show it's working

```js
const vs = `
    attribute vec4 v_position;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = v_position;
    }     
`;

const fs = `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
       gl_FragColor = vec4(fract(gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(16., 32.)),0,1); 
    }
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var shader_program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(shader_program);
var vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shader_program, "v_position");
var quad_vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var quad_vertex_buffer_data = new Float32Array([ 
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
     1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
     1.0,  1.0, 0.0]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_vertex_buffer_data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute)
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

I'd suggest you read some [WebGL tutorials](https://weglfundamentals.org/).